# Can a Filipino visiting the UK on a visitor visa travel to Paris on Eurostar?

Tags: visas, france, filipino-citizens, eurostar

Or do they need a separate visa for a day trip to France as well?

The UK visa is a standard tourist visa in a Philippines passport.

I couldn't find the answer on any other websites, other than the fact that French immigration check documentation in London prior to boarding.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The UK and France have different visa regimes. France is part of the Schengen Area and the traveller will require a Schengen visa to enter France.

Comment: It is best to apply from your home country. Once you have been in the UK for 3 months you can apply for a Schengan visa. https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-uk/ . You do of course need a visa in the UK that is longer than 3 months, or get it extended.

Answer (score 9):

Whether for ten minutes or three months, you need a Schengen visitor visa. The UK is not part of Schengen, your visa has no power there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply from your home country, also prove you are not going to work there..having a UK visa is no assurance you will get a Schengen visa...

Answer (score -4):

Without a visa, your friend will never be able to even get on the train.  There is a customs point in London between the street and the train platform.

Comment: This doesn't really add any useful information. Other answers have already said that a visa is necessary so the asker surely won't attempt to travel without one.